# Trying to parse URL using Regex [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some trouble parsing one part of the following URL out:

```
http://port-80.********************************************.box.************.com/********/search/?sid=123875&brands=DELL|KROCKS&sort=popularity
```

I am trying to parse out the following: DELL|KROCKS.

So far I have the following regex expression which works to a certain extent:

```
/brands=(.*)[\&?]/
```

What the above does is if the & character is after the brands, it will get the following: DELL|KROCKS. However, if the & is not there, it will get the following: DELL|KROCKS&sort=popularity.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Why not just match `[^&?]*` instead of `(.*)[\&?]`?

Comment: How, if "the & is not there", can it "get the following: DELL|KROCKS&sort=popularity"?

Comment: Have you tried using any URL parsing libraries to break the query portion down into useful parts?

Comment: This worked: [^&?]* ! Thank you very much! brands=([^&?]*)

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic URL parser.

Like this: [How to get the value from URL Parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter)

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split("+").join(" ");

    var params = {}, tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])]
            = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}
var query = getQueryParams("http://port-80.********************************************.box.************.com/********/search/?sid=123875&brands=DELL|KROCKS&sort=popularity");
alert(query.brands);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this brands=(.*?)(?:&|$)

This is a great tool for testing regex with groups 
https://www.debuggex.com/r/WgYVhtG4Zrn4f5gH